# SharePoint/InfoPath 2010 – Filtering InfoPath form to show current user only

Tags: infopath, filter, form, user

First post on here from a relatively novice user of SharePoint 2010!

I am currently implementing an annual leave recording system for staff. I’ve created two lists to hold the data – a list for the user’s details (name, manager, etc) and a list for the actual leave requests (date to, date from, etc).

I have also created a customised InfoPath form for entering data (which features multiple data connections) but I’m having trouble filtering the form to show items for only the current user – it currently shows all the items in the list.

It was suggested that I use the [Me] filter to do this. This makes sense but I am not sure how to execute this. I have created a view, using the [Me] filter, to only show items for the current user – but can I apply this to the InfoPath form? Or am I on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the wrong track. You can create your own kind of "view" in Infopath with filtering your data connections directly. Here is a link which explains this with a User-Field from SharePoint

http://www.bjw.co.nz/developer/sharepoint-2010/100-infopath-filter-data-shown-in-dropdown-list

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you Gwny, I will try this. Apologies for the late acknowledgement but I have been on leave.